# XPath intersection of two sets

Tags: xpath

I need to extract all links from a html document having text as the inner element and not a reference to an image. Basically I would like to do a doc.select("//a/attribute::href") for all elements in a tree where doc.select("//a/text()") returns anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can write conditions in XPath in a predicate in square brackets, e.g. `//a[text()]/@href` selects the `href` attributes of all link (`a`) elements that have at least one text node child. Or if you want to make sure there is no `img` child element in the link you can use e.g. `//a[not(img)]/@href`.